# Invisible border applied to inputs on Apple IOS devices

Tags: javascript, css, iphone, reactjs

Inputs are having an almost invisible border applied on iOS devices, on all browsers.

How do I remove or prevent this styling from being applied?

```js
const StyledInputString = styled.input`
    width: 40%;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #8f8fa1;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding-left: 20px;
    height: 56px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    &:focus {
      border-bottom: 2px solid #03a900;
      color: black;
    }
```

Example image with the styles applied:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `border-radius` property.

```
input {
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Also try setting

```
input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```